# How to add onclick="return false" in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I use javascript code to disable click on link in php

> onclick="return false"

but not working

What I have tried so far:

```
$data .= '<td bgcolor="FFFFCC">'."<a href='http://priceha.ir/' onclick=\"return false\">.$row2->model.</a>".'</td>';

$data .= '<td bgcolor="FFFFCC">'."<a href='http://priceha.ir/' onclick='return false'>.$row2->model.</a>".'</td>';
```

Comment: try this `function() { return false; }`

Comment: Probably because the onclick written inline will be superceeded by your actual javascript that registers click handlers only after that page is completely loaded

Comment: onClick="event.preventDefault(); return false;"

Answer (score 1):

option 1

```
<a href='' disabled='disabled'>Click Here</a>
```

option 2

```
<style>
.not-active {
 pointer-events: none;
 cursor: default;
}
</style>
```

option 3 make sure return false is in double quote

```
<a onclick="return false" href="" />click</a>
```